# What bottom bracket will fit the Ribble Endurance SLR?

Tags: frames, bottom-bracket, ribble

Will a Shimano Ultegra BBR60 bottom bracket fit the Ribble Endurance SLR frame? I cant seem to find any technical information on the frame anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://www.ribblecycles.co.uk/ribble-endurance-sl-r-series-frameset/

> **Bottom Bracket:** Press Fit BB86.

A [Shimano BBR60](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/SM-BBR60.html) is threaded:

> SM-BBR60
>
> SHIMANO ULTEGRA - Bottom Bracket - Threaded - HOLLOWTECH II - 68/70 mm
> shell width

So no, the BBR60 won't fit.

Something like a [Wheels Manufacturing BB86/92](https://wheelsmfg.com/bottom-brackets/bb86-92/bb86-92-outboard-abec-3-bb-for-24mm-shimano-cranks-black.html) would fit, though.

And it won't start making noises after 4 km.